# How can i insert a hyperlink in an image using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don not want to treat image as a hyperlink but want to add hyperlink in an image.

Comment: Please try solving it on your own... You want to add hyperlink in an image. But in comment to my answer, you told that I need image with clickable link which i want to use it to send it on whatsapp... Ask properly and clearly. Check stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: ok ... i think i am very much clear that i want to create image which contains hyperlink...anywaz thanks for the help ..!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

```
import Tkinter as tk

image_link = tk.Label(text_widget, image=my_image, cursor="left_ptr")
image_link.bind("<1>", do_something)
text_widget.window_create("insert", window=image_link)
```

Comment: Thanks...But I need image with clickable link which i want to use it to send it on whatsapp ... but this will open a window ....how can i get the image...

Comment: Are you trying something on your own? or are you entirely dependent on me for complete solution?

Comment: I am trying something but it is not working..if u can provide complete solution it wd b great...